# How to set height and width of a div in a same equal way in every block in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

This one i want to display. In here i want to display all these in same way same height & width.But in here bottom part height will be larger if the title has many words.

[image]

This is my html code block

```
<div [style.width.%]="105" [style.height.%]="25">
<div matRipple [matRippleColor]="primary" class="m-tile">
    <div class="a-tile-graph a-tile-graph--hotel">
        <div class="titles">
            <div class="head">{{name}}</div>
            <div class="sub">{{level}}</div>
        </div>
        <div id="{{chartId}}" class="graph"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="o-tile-content" [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px':14}">
        <div class="a-tile-btn"><i class="fa fa-signal"></i></div>
        <div class="a-tile-title">{{name}}</div>
        <div class="a-tile-value"><span class="currency">$</span>{{getFormattedValues(ttv)}}</div>
        <div class="a-tile-count">{{getFormattedValues(ttc)}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

how could i fix this?

Comment: Could you add the renderd html output? or a working snippet that shows your problem.

Comment: This is my rendered html that part

Comment: No that is what you have written for angular it will be a lot easier to help if you add the html that is rendered in your browser

Comment: Are u telling if i inspect it ?.The image i have attached is showing currently the way how it' s displaying

Comment: Yeah either provide a link to the code so we can see it rendered or add the html from the inspector and create a working snippet

Comment: Can you show us your css please?

Comment: Actually that no css here